# How to append to a list in a function loop (append not working?)

Tags: r

I am trying make a list in a loop of the unique values in my `df$RecipientLastName`. I made a `uniqueid` col for this, then made an empty list and tried to get R to append each value from the `uniqueid` list to a list called `li` (so that users can type in the # of participants). This is how the code looks.

```
uniqueid <- unique(df$RecipientLastName, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA)
uniqueid2.list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)

loops <- function(numpar) {
  for (i in 1:numpar) {
    parID <- uniqueid[i]
    li <- append(uniqueid2.list, parID)
  }
  return(li)
}

loops(9)
```

This is the output I am getting when I use the loops function with number = 9. 136 is the value of the 9th item in uniqueid. I want it to return the first 9 values of the list.

```
[[1]]
[1] 136
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `li` value at each iteration in the loop so you only get the last value.

```
uniqueid <- unique(df$RecipientLastName, incomparables = FALSE, 
                   fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA)


loops <- function(numpar) {
  uniqueid2.list <- vector(mode = "list", length = numpar)
  for (i in 1:numpar) {
    parID <- uniqueid[i]
    uniqueid2.list[[i]] <- append(uniqueid2.list, parID)
  }
  return(uniqueid2.list)
}
```

---

But you don't really need a loop here. You can do :

```
result <- uniqueid[1:numpar]
#If you want it as a list
result <- as.list(result)
```